# Unit test controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I make an ionic app and it finish but when i start to add tests to it I face a problem with $resources ,in this case I have this Controller :

```
  .controller('newAccountCtrl', function($scope, $window, $rootScope, API, $ionicPopup, $state) {
    $scope.newData = {};
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {

        $scope.newData = {};
    });
    $scope.newInfo = function() {
        API.newAccountInfo().update({ restCode: $scope.newData.restore_code }, $scope.newData, function(res, header) {
            $rootScope.popup('success', "OKAY");
            $window.location.href = '#/login';
        }, function(err) {
            if (err.data == null)
                $rootScope.popup("Error", "no connection");
            else
                $rootScope.popup('error', err.data.error);
        });
    }
})
```

and in the service i make a request using $resources in function :

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('API', function($rootScope, $resource, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, $window) { return {
          newAccountInfo: function() {
            return $resource(base + '/restoreinfo/:restCode', { restCode: '@_restCode' }, {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            }, {
                stripTrailingSlashes: false
            });
        }}});
```

and in the my test the following code:

```
describe('newAccountCtrl', function() {

var controller,
    deferredLogup, scope, $q;
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('starter'));
// TODO: Load the App Module
beforeEach(module('starter.controllers'));
beforeEach(module('starter.services'));

// TODO: Instantiate the Controller and Mocks
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$q_, $rootScope, _API_) {
    $q = _$q_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    API = _API_;

    spyOn(API, 'newAccountInfo').and.callThrough(function(callback) {
        deferredLogup.promise.then(callback);
        return { $promise: deferredLogup.promise };
    });

    controller = $controller('newAccountCtrl', {
        '$scope': scope,
        API: API
    });

}));
it('#newAccountInfo', function() {

    scope.newInfo();

    expect(API.newAccountInfo.update).toHaveBeenCalled();

})   });
```

but I get the error :

```
Expected a spy, but got undefined.
```

What I misunderstand here, the code work perfect

Comment: Well yeah, `API.newAccountInfo.update` is not a spy. The error message is pretty clear

Comment: Why does your factory return a function that creates the same resource each time? Shouldn't it just return the resource itself?

Comment: Hallo,because i have too many other functions for others resources ,here i mention just one, there is no way to create a spy on it ?

Comment: @Phil there is many tutorial that make an Service serves multiple $resource urls / data sources, so i do it these way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just macke factory return the resources direct and remove the functions .